# How to keep table schemas in sync across multiple databases

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, amazon-aurora

For compliance, we need to duplicate database schemas across multiple regions.

Is there an easy way to keep the table schema across all databases in sync so that we know that all tables are being changed? Manual updating looks to be error-prone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Did you consider Replication?  That is standard; syncing is not.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I am using Aurora MySQL

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I am not seeing for replication. I am checking for a procedure to sync with 4 databases.

Answer (score 0):

If by “synch” you mean data can be inserted, updated or deleted in either DB, and the differences are resolved so both DBs have the same data, and data isn’t lost in the process — that cannot be achieved, provably impossible. Go read Leslie Lamport’s paper from 1978.

A one-directional approach (aka replication) works fine.

A two-or-more way approach where you tolerate some data loss and unpredictable changes to your data (aka eventual consistency) works fine.

Comment: NDB cluster uses "eventual consistency" successfully for some applications.  (I would not use it for a banking application.)